# How do you use pdf.js to get text content of client stored pdf?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, pdf.js

I am working on a web app that needs to read a pdf with pdf.js. I have a file input on my page that chooses the file. I have the `document.getElementById("...").value` as the pdf's url. When I run it, it says:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load c:\fakepath\vocab_list_15_8th_grade.pdf. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
awe:1 Unhandled promise rejection Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected", [[PromiseValue]]: UnknownErrorException}"

I imagine this is because the file is stored locally. How do I get around this error?

Comment: I don't know php. Can I do the same in Node.js? or better yet without server side?

Comment: You cannot access the Client's Files. The files can be uploaded to your Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with pdf.js per se.  pdf.js just happens to be trying to load a file using XMLHttpRequest.

The problem is that you gave pdf.js a path to a local file (`c:\fakepath\vocab_list_15_8th_grade.pdf`).  Your web browser won't let a web page load the local file for security reasons, even if the web page is also local.  The way to get around this is just to run a web server locally that contains both your web app and your PDF.

If you have Python installed you can do this really easily by running:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

...from the directory you want to serve from.

But it looks like you're on Windows (judging from the `C:\` in your path).  I don't know the easiest way to run a simple web server on Windows without having Python installed.